# Twitter API V2 403: Forbidden using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I'm not able to authenticate using my twitter developer account even though my account active

```
import tweepy
consumer_key= 'XX1'
consumer_secret= 'XX2'
access_token= 'XX3'
access_token_secret= 'XX4'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
api.update_status("Hello Tweepy")
```

i'm getting error :

```
Forbidden: 403 Forbidden

453 - You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve
```

There is no option to move to Essential to Elevated on the developer portal. any suggestion ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that Essential access can use only Twitter API v2

The code should be

```
import tweepy
consumer_key= 'x'
consumer_secret= 'xx'
access_token= 'xxx'
access_token_secret= 'xxxx'

client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key= consumer_key,consumer_secret= consumer_secret,access_token= access_token,access_token_secret= access_token_secret)
query = 'news'
tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query, max_results=10)
for tweet in tweets.data:
    print(tweet.text)
```

Thanks to  https://twittercommunity.com/t/403-forbidden-using-tweepy/162435/2

Comment: But this says tweepy has no attribute called Client

Comment: I am getting tweepy.errors.Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized
Unauthorized

Comment: Could you please clarify is 'search' tweets API  are available for free developer account?

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to "Elevate" your access unless your app has these specific requirements:
[image]

Where the "Essential" (the one that you have by default) access has the following ones:
[image]

In the case that the OP is referring, he is trying to send a tweet, so the code for using Tweepy + Twitter API v2 will be something like this:

```py
import tweepy
client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key="",
                    consumer_secret="",
                    access_token="",
                    access_token_secret="")
# Replace the text with whatever you want to Tweet about
response = client.create_tweet(text='hello world')
```

Remember that your access_token + access_token_secret will have to be generated with Read&Write permissions in order to be able to send tweets (Otherwise you will get a 403 error with previous code):
[image]

See https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-do-i-change-my-app-from-read-only-to-read-write/163624/4 for more details on how to do it.

Comment: this worked for me in Feb 2023 running into the same error as OP

Answer (score 3):

There are options in the dashboard. You have to submit an application for access.

Refer image:

[image: Dashboard]

Comment: Clicking on Apply for Elevated  is directing me to https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/petition/academic/is-it-right-for-you

Comment: These tabs seem to have been removed.  I only see tabs for "Free" and "Basic" then a link to apply for Enterprise access.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I had created the tokens prior to setting the app to read/write mode. The tokens use the prior setting, so the tokens need to recreated after changing to read/write mode.

from here: https://twittercommunity.com/t/forbidden-to-use-retweet-v2/159706